# Why won't my PS2 play PS1 games?

Tags: ps2

My PS2 won't play PS1 games. I have *Driver 2: Back on the Streets*, *Psy Deck*, *Courier Crisis*, and a bunch of other games that won't play on my PS2.

Comment: Do you have an original or slim PS2?

Comment: Also, where did you buy the PS2 and where did you buy the games? Driver 2 is only called "Back on the Streets" in the UK, so if you have a UK PS1 game in a US PS2 (or some other cross-region combination), that might be the reason.

Comment: Aren't both able to play PS1 games? What's the condition of your games?

Comment: @Gmoneyrocks I believe so, but it's a persistent rumour that they don't, so someone was going to ask. I'm really just fishing for more info, because as is, the question doesn't give us enough to do more than guess wildly why it's not working. Yeah, game condition is a good question! PS2s are rumoured less forgiving of scratched PS1 games than PS2 games.

Comment: Word. Also good call on the region lock. Also I believe that PS3s are fully able to play PS1 games. But still not sure if it's region free. Not all PS3s can PS2 games though.

Comment: Many PS2's are simply old and decrepit these days. Mine died a death recently :( (not to say yours is...simply lamenting)

Comment: @Gmoneyrocks PS3s *are* region locked when it comes to playing PS1 games. I own a European PS3 and it will not play my NA PS1 games.

Comment: I just got the original Ps2, yesterday driver 2 backon the streets worked and played properly

Comment: Don't remember if this will help for PS1 games / your situation (leaning towards 'no'), but since a few people here are talking about failing PS2s ... Optical drives often go long before the rest of the system. You might want to install a softmod while you can; the current ones are easy, non-destructive, and will be a big help when the drive goes (you can play your (legally owned) games off other media, among other things).   Also helps w/ cross-region issues (for PS2 games, at least).

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to different BIOS.

There is NTSC-->30frames/second (USA,Japan.etc..)
and PAL-->25frames/second (Mostly Europe)

Some Pal version of games wont run on the NTSC and NTSC wont run on PAL.

Also note that
these PlayStation games are incompatible with all models of PlayStation 2

- Arcade Party Pak
- Arcade's Greatest Hits/Atari 2
- Fighter Maker
- Final Fantasy Anthology
- Judge Dredd
- Monkey Hero
- Mortal Kombat Trilogy
- Tomba!
- Lunar 2: Eternal Blue Complete

And the following games are incompatible with the SCPH-75001, 
"slim", model PlayStation 2

- 102 Dalmatians: Puppies to the Rescue
- Akuji the Heartless
- Barbie Race and Ride
- Broken Helix
- Bubsy 3D
- Driver
- Gundam Battle Assault
- The Hive
- Hooters Road Trip
- In Cold Blood
- Jampack Vol. 2
- Land Before Time: Great Valley Racing Adventure
- NFL Xtreme
- NHL 2000
- NHL 2001
- NHL Blades of Steel 2000
- NHL Rock the Rink
- Nuclear Strike
- One
- PO'ed
- Powerboat Racing (VR Sports)
- Rascal
- Rush Down
- Sentient
- Speed Punks
- Super Puzzle Fighter II Turbo
- Syphon Filter 2
- Syphon Filter 3
- Tomorrow Never Dies
- Ultimate Fighting Championship
- Worms

Comment: the best solution I have found for problems like this requires a softmod at least. you will be glad you did it when the laser gives out entirely....check out freemcboot....If you dont already know someone with a modded console you will need goldeneye agent under fire and a blank dvd-r disk and a computer with a program called apache tools....you are going to copy an iso of the disk(or just download it for convenience) and trade the driving.elf file for any .elf file available on sks apps...most comonly ulaunchelf or the installer for freemcboot.

Comment: Here's the reference for this that I just found:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_games_incompatible_with_PlayStation_2